# Setting the type of a button, ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Creating a button dynamically and then trying to set it to be a `button` rather then the default `submit`.

Here is how I am creating the button and setting the type.

```
var pickButton = document.createElement("button");
pickButton.type = "button";
```

IE8 will error out, saying:

```
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
pickButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
```